# Pyaudio frames_per_buffer and callback mode issue

Tags: python, pyaudio

I am wondering how to record data on fly.
If I get it right, in blocking mode PyAudio records N(frames_per_buffer) frames and return it, when record next N frames starting with N+1 frame. E.g. if CHUNK size = 1024, first return will be frames from 1 to 1024, and second will be frames from 1025 to 2048.

I want to run stream in the way I can get firstly 1 - 1024 frames, then 2 - 1025, then 3 - 1026 or with any other step size.

Is it possible? Is callback mode can help with it?

I tried to use callback function but I do not really understand how it works...

Comment: Please share code with entire traceback error